# Can I post my manuscript to Academia, arXiv, personal website, and submit it to a green Journal at the same time?

Tags: publications

If my manuscript is accepted and I post my preprint on the arXiv, that will be fine. However, if I submit my manuscript to a "Open Green Access" journal, at the same time, I post my manuscript on two or more public databases (Academia, arXiv), is this allowed?

Comment: The answer to your question depends upon the specific journal's policy. Some allow pre-prints to be posted. Others do not.

Comment: What do you mean by a "green journal"?

Comment: @Anyon Probably "Open Green Access" or whatever this is called nowadays.

Comment: @PaulYuan See Richard Erickson's comment. It applies to your question and to the comment you just posted.

Comment: ArXiv does _not_ require peer review.  (I'm a moderator.)

Answer (score 3):

Chances are extremely good you can, but check with the journal/publisher. Policies vary from publisher to publisher, but most publishers will allow you to share a preprint.

[Example policy from Elsevier](https://www.elsevier.com/about/policies/sharing):

> **Preprint**
>
> - Authors can share their preprint anywhere at any time.
> - If accepted for publication, we encourage authors to link from the preprint to their formal publication via its Digital Object Identifier (DOI). Millions of researchers have access to the formal publications on ScienceDirect, and so links will help your users to find, access, cite, and use the best available version.
> - Authors can update their preprints on arXiv or RePEc with their accepted manuscript .
>
> Please note:
>
> - Some society-owned titles and journals that operate double-blind peer review have different preprint policies. Please check the journals Guide for Authors for further information.
> - Preprints should not be added to or enhanced in any way in order to appear more like, or to substitute for, the final versions of articles.